# Security alert - how to manage the download

Tags: upgrade

I am new to the CiviCRM interface, and am trying to build a conference registration form within www.jesuitschoolsnetwork.org.  I have repeatedly been notified that there is a needed update due to a security issue. Our site runs on Drupal 7x, and I have downloaded civicrm-4.6.8-drupal.gz, but am not sure what to do with the download.

Comment: Closing because the only answer to this question is "read [the documentation](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installation+and+Upgrades)". If you have a specific question *about* the documentation having already read it, that would be different.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange and the CiviCRM community! Hope you will enjoy using CiviCRM! (And i also agree with @Coleman answer, please read first, or ask questions like "where to read?" to indicate that you are willing to do an effort yourself in trying to solve your issue.)

Comment: Tim,  here's the documentation on upgrading CiviCRM :  http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrading+CiviCRM+for+Drupal+7

Answer (score 3):

Follow the instructions at http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrading+CiviCRM+for+Drupal+7. If you have questions about the documentation, please post a separate question back here.